# How to update every specific value for all objects in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

So I have an application that involves giving an estimated wait time. I currently have my schema set up to have a `waitTime` value estimated off the count of the number of items in the collection. This works find.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to reduce the estimated wait time by 15 for every person in the database whenever someone is deleted from the database.

For instance say there are four people currently in the database. Each person has a respective assigned wait time of 15, 30, 45, and 60. Then lets say that the second person in the database is removed (i.e. they cancel their appointment). Then the two people who were after that second person need to have their estimated wait time updated to 30 and 45 minutes.

```
{
    "_id": "qntsyc9RZqkbHnSGM",
    "Name": "John",
    "PhoneNumber": "5555555555",
    "createdAt": "2017-04-05T05:05:46.024Z",
    "currentStatus": "Waiting",
    "waitTime": 30 //this is the value I want to reduce for every object in the database
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

P.S. This is basically creating an Index but I have had issues trying to create an Index for my db. I've tried using createIndex() and ensureIndex(), but have had no success (maybe I'm just doing it wrong). If there is a way to create an index for my db then I can work with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB **update** operation is singular. Hence you need pass `{multi:true}` to update multiple records.  Try this,

```
db.dbname.update({},{ $inc: {'waitTime':-15} }, {multi:true});//Mongo query
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the value by 15 for all of them, you'll want to use the $inc operator.  It excepts negative values, so you can use it to increment or decrement.

The update would look something like this, just change the name of the collection:

```
db.epace.update({}, {$inc:{waitTime: -15}}, {multi:true})
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to decrease the waitime after the deleted record you need to update using $inc operator with negative value

```
db.queue.update({}, {$inc: {waitTime: -15 }},{ multi:true })
```

but this will update all the document even the first one so you have to update only those document after the deleted one not the previous one.

you can get those document easily using

`db.queue.update( 
{ created_at: { $gt: timestamp }},
{$inc: {waitingTime: -15 }},{multi:true})`

Comment: So I tried this but I get this error in the console: allow-deny.js:494 Uncaught 
errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.", details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}

Comment: You need to do this server-side.